# How do I make images open in a new tab by default?

Tags: urls

When I insert a large image into a post, I would like the image to open in a new browser tab rather than within the existing tab.

I know that this can be accomplished by adding `target="_blank"` to the link, but how do I add this attribute to the image links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you cannot write codes:

There is a Plugin [MDC Target Blank](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mdc-target-blank/), that'll solve the issue. When someone clicks on a link (or an image that is hyperlinked), it'll force to open in a new tab. It adds `target="_blank"` to `a` tags.

Older versions of this plugin had a bug, that's fixed in new versions. So, don't worry about the plugin ratings.

### If you can write codes:

Add this code to your theme's `functions.php` file

```
function mdc_target_blank($content) {
    $post_string = $content;
    $post_string = str_replace('<a', '<a target="_blank"', $post_string);
    return $post_string;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'mdc_target_blank' );
```

Comment: Someone just down-voted my answer! May I know why?

Comment: Don't take the downvotes personally but there might be two reasons someone downvoted it: First you haven't stated your plugin affiliation (it looks like you're promoting your own plugin here) and secondly the code doesn't take into the account links already with the target attribute. But it might be something else I missed? But I'm sure you can  adjust your answer ;-)

Comment: how to fix only for image link

Answer (score 0):

Goto Image details in the Visual editor.

Tick the dropdown Advanced options.

Check the *Open link in a new window/tab*

Press Update, then Update the post again!!!!!

Comment: thx. In such a case, Updating all posts is required. I am sure existing a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Now its very easy. Most themes support this method without the use of separate plugins.
[image: Edit the image after inserting into the post]

Change the link to image URL and check open in a new tab
[image: Change the link to image URL and check open in a new tab]

Save the image.